# Getting value from different react component - onClick of a LOG button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
 function Paste() {
  const Log = "LOG";
  const [logList, setLogList] = useState([{ text: "Yes", id: 1 }]);
  const [newLogValue, setNewLogValue] = useState(0);

  const appendToList = () => {
    alert(newLogValue);
    const newLogList = [
      ...logList,
      { text: newLogValue, id: logList.length + 1 },
    ];
    setLogList(newLogList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        style={{
          width: "24%",
          height: "80%",
          display: "block",
          marginLeft: "3%",
          verticalAlign: "top",
          border: "3px solid #F08080",
          background: "#808080",
        }}
        onChange={(e) => setNewLogValue(e.target.value)}
      ></textarea>
      <button
        style={{
          width: "24.3%",
          height: "10%",
          display: "block",
          float: "left",
          marginLeft: "3%",
        }}
        value={Log}
      >
        <p
          style={{ FontFace: "Mono", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "14px" }}
          onClick={appendToList}
        >
          LOG
        </p>
      </button>
      <List logList={logList}></List>
    </>
  );
}
```

This code is not working consistently, It randomly captures the value. Most of the time it doesnt. I tried different events like onBlur, onBlurCapture, onChange, onChangeCapture but no difference. Is there any way to get the value from textArea and append it to logList ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `onClick` event handler to the `button`, and not to the content of the `button`.

```
<button value={Log} onClick={appendToList}>
```

Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const List = ({ logList }) => (
  <ul>
    {logList.map(({ text, id }) => (
      <li key={id}>{text}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

function Paste() {
  const Log = "LOG";
  const [logList, setLogList] = useState([{
    text: 'Yes',
    id: 1
  }]);
  const [newLogValue, setNewLogValue] = useState(0);

  const appendToList = () => {
    const newLogList = [...logList, {
      text: newLogValue,
      id: logList.length + 1
    }];
    setLogList(newLogList);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea onChange={e => setNewLogValue(e.target.value)}></textarea>
      <button value={Log} onClick={appendToList}>
        <p>LOG</p>
      </button>
      <List logList={logList}></List>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Paste />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

generally, you're not supposed to put **block elements ( p tag)  inside of inline elements** (button tag ). Despite this, your code  is working but your button randomly captures the value because you're clicking in the `button  tag`, not the  `p tag` where you have the **onCkick function**, just move the onClick function to the button tag

```
<button value={Log} onClick={appendToList} style={{...}}>
        <p style={{...}} >LOG</p>
 </button>
```

this will work,  But  your code will be much cleaner if you get rid of the p tag from the button

Comment: You didnt understood the question, I have to get the value of <textarea> on the click ob burtton and append it to list.

Comment: My Bad, Why I asked this queation, I though I was adding it to button. Code was jumbled up in text editor.

Comment: this happens all the time